# section is not following div css rules

Tags: html, css

I have made multiple sections using a div called .luxxreno and all of them look the same which they should do, however there is one which is slightly miss aligned and isn't aligning, can someone tell me how I can align it and what is causing the issue, the section that is not aligning is called 'kyran, competitive player'.

HTML and CSS

```css
/*PLAYER PAGE*/

.container {
  padding: 2.5em 1.25em 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  border-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
}

h1 span {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}

.meet-the-owner h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 1.5625em;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
}

.meet-the-owner-top h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 1.5625em;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  padding: 2.5em;
}

.luxxreno {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.luxxreno img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 550px;
  position: inherit;
  bottom: 4em;
}

.meet-the-owner {
  padding: 3.125em;
  border-top: 0.125em solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
}

.q-l {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.questions p {
  padding: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.luxxreno h2 {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  left: 0.2em;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 1.9em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.status {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  left: 0.2em;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 1.9em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.owner {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.luxx-socials {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="player-bios">

  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      <span>Players</span>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner-top">

    <h3>Meet the Owner</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/luxx.jpg">
    <div class="q-l">
      <div class="questions">
        <h2 class="luxx-name">LUXX RENO</h2>
        <h2 class="owner">OWNER</h2>
        <p>Real Name: <b>Cory George</b></p>
        <p>Online Name: <b>Luxx Reno</b></p>
        <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Duck Hunter/Super Nintendo</b></p>
        <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Fortnite</b></p>
        <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br><b>Mimicry, so I'd be able to mimic and super power I see.</b></p>
        <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Billy Raffoul</b></p>
        <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Won lots of medals for swimming!</b></p>
      </div>

      <div class="luxx-socials">
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPqsHNuWTAbckHg4R3WAJIg" target=”_blank”>
            <li>487 @ YouTube</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/luxxreno/?hl=en" target=”_blank”>
            <li>2.6k @ Instagram</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/luxxreno" target=”_blank”>
            <li>3k @ Twitch</li>
          </a><br>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/LuxxReno" target=”_blank”>
            <li>2.5k @ Twitter</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxxreno?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1" target=”_blank”>
            <li>657k @ TikTok</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>Content Creator</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/avg-c.png">
    <div class="q-l">
      <div class="questions">
        <h2 class="luxx-name">AVERAGEANT</h2>
        <h2 class="owner">Content Creator</h2>
        <p>Real Name: <b>Anthony Bryne</b></p>
        <p>Online Name: <b>Average Ant</b></p>
        <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Modern Warfare 2</b></p>
        <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Call Of Duty Warzone</b></p>
        <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br> <b>Mind Reader</b></p>
        <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Lil Tjay</b></p>
        <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Best Swimmer on Twitch</b></p>
      </div>

      <div class="luxx-socials">
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Abzzino/featured" target=”_blank”>
            <li>360 @ YouTube</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_abzzino_/" target=”_blank”>
            <li>193 @ Instagram</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/abzzinok" target=”_blank”>
            <li>2.6k @ Twitch</li>
          </a><br>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/_Abzzino_" target=”_blank”>
            <li>142 @ Twitter</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@abzzinoyt?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
            <li>23.6k @ TikTok</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/kyran-c.png">
    <div class="q-l">
      <div class="questions">
        <h2 class="luxx-name">KEEZO</h2>
        <h2 class="owner">COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h2>
        <p>Real Name: <b>Kyran Garden</b></p>
        <p>Online Name: <b>KEEZO</b></p>
        <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Call Of Duty 3</b></p>
        <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Warzone</b></p>
        <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br> <b>Flying</b></p>
        <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Drake</b></p>
        <p>Hidden Talents: <b>I'm good at football.</b></p>
      </div>

      <div class="luxx-socials">
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/LKeezo" target=”_blank”>
            <li>400 @ Twitch</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/KEEZZ0" target=”_blank”>
            <li>1.2k @ Twitter</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@kkeezo?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
            <li>1.1k @ TikTok</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>Content Manager</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/brad-c.png" class="luxx-img">
    <div class="q-l">
      <div class="questions">
        <h2 class="luxx-name">SPODERBRAD</h2>
        <h2 class="owner">Content Manager</h2>
        <p>Real Name: <b>Brad</b></p>
        <p>Online Name: <b>SpoderBrad</b></p>
        <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Metal Gear Solid</b></p>
        <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Splitgate</b></p>
        <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br><b>Honestly don’t want a super power just wanna <br> be Iron Man.</b></p>
        <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <br> <b>Drake or Eminem can’t decide</b></p>
        <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Best Free Kick Taker on Twitch.</b></p>
      </div>

      <div class="luxx-socials">
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnqgXWWmmg1F3L919lzT6aQ" target=”_blank”>
            <li>353 @ YouTube</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spoderbrad/?hl=en-gb" target=”_blank”>
            <li>115 @ Instagram</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”>
            <li>2.1k @ Twitch</li>
          </a><br>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”>
            <li>392 @ Twitter</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@spoderbrad?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
            <li>60k @ TikTok</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: which div exactly you are talkin about??

Comment: if you want to create sections, then use scetions not divs.

Comment: In what way is it not aligning?

Comment: the div is .luxxreno